# Converse.js Dev environment

Tags: converse.js

I am trying to get a development environment up and running so I can play around with things a bit. Everything goes well `make dev` and "node_modules" appears etc, however, when I try to load the dependencies "Loading converse.js and its dependencies" the line `<script data-main="main" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>` doesn't work as intended as there is no "main.js". Have I missed a step or being silly and not knowing something?

Comment: Where did you see that you need to add `<script data-main="main" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>` is that still in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: https://conversejs.org/docs/html/developer_guidelines.html#installing-the-development-and-front-end-dependencies

Comment: I was following that on how to set up my development environment

Comment: That documentation is out of date. I'll update it soon. In the meantime, just look at fullscreen.html in the repo. You can run `make watchjs` to automatically regenerate `dist/converse.js`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks